# What python equivalent of Sinatra would you recommend?

Tags: python, frameworks, sinatra, web-frameworks

I like the [sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) framework, but might have to work in python. A quick web search has uncovered a few python equivalents including [itty](http://toastdriven.com/fresh/itty-sinatra-inspired-micro-framework/), [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and [juno](http://github.com/breily/juno).

I'd like to know people's experience of these, or other sinatra equivalents. Which would you recommend?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Okay. So I'm biased because I'm the author of Flask, but here something to help you make the pick:

- itty - very minimal framework, Bottle is probably a more stable alternative if you want a single file installation.
- Flask - new and actively developed, shaped similar to Sinatra but also differs in a few points. Large number of extensions for SQLAlchemy, CouchDB and more.
- Juno - not updated for a year. Usually not the best sign.

Besides the ones you mentioned there is also Bottle which is similar to Flask but more minimalistic.  Unlike Flask it also re-implements everything from ground up instead of building on an independent foundation like Werkzeug.

Other alternatives is web.py, one of the first microframeworks ever.  Same rule as bottle: re-implements everything from the ground up.

Comment: The home site of Flask seems to be down: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://flask.pocoo.org/ (at least at the moment I'm writing this comment)